# Will (N)RVO be applied with my function in this situation?

Tags: c++, rvo, nrvo

I have the following code: (ok, in reality it's much more complicated, but I simplified it to make it easier to understand. so please disregard the things that seems stupid. I can't change them in my real situation)

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

ReportManager g_report_generator;

struct ReportManager
{
    // I know, using c_str in this case is stupid. 
    // but just assume that it has to be this way
    string GenerateReport() { string report("test"); return report.c_str(); }
}

string DoIt(bool remove_all)
{
    if(g_report_generator.isEmpty())
        return string();

    string val = g_report_generator.GenerateReport();

    if(remove_all)
        g_report_generator.clear();

    return val;
}

void main()
{
    string s = DoIt(true);
}
```

Will (N)RVO be applied with my functions?
I did a bit of research, and it would seem like it, but I'm not really convinced and I'd like a second opinion (or more).

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: It may or may not happen.  The only way to know for certain is to check the assembly.

Comment: If you had `return report;` then NRVO would be nearly a sure thing. However since you are using `.c_str()` to construct another separate string, I think that's a stretch to consider for NRVO.

Comment: Which function? `DoIt` or `GenerateReport`?

Comment: Both. Sorry, I thought I wrote functions, not function. My bad.

Comment: Please post actual [mcve] not pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem I rewrote it.

```
#include <string>


struct string : std::string {
    using std::string::string;

    string(string&& s) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    string(string const&) {
        exit(-2);
    }

    string() {}
};

struct ReportManager
{
    // I know, using c_str in this case is stupid. 
    // but just assume that it has to be this way
    string GenerateReport()
    {
        string report("test");
        return report.c_str();
    }
    bool isEmpty() const { return true; }
    void clear() const {}
};

ReportManager g_report_generator;

string DoIt(bool remove_all)
{
    if(g_report_generator.isEmpty())
        return string();

    string val = g_report_generator.GenerateReport();

    if(remove_all)
        g_report_generator.clear();

    return val;
}

int main()
{
    string s = DoIt(true);
}
```

The trick with this rewriting is that elision permits skipping copy/move ctors.  So every time we actually copy an object (even if inlined), we'll insert an `exit` clause; only by elision can we avoid it.

`GenerateReport` has no (N)RVO or any kind of elision, other than possibly under as-if.  I doubt a compiler will be able to prove that, especially if the string is non-static and large enough to require heap storage.

For `DoIt` both NRVO and RVO is possible.  Elision is legal there, even with side effects.

[MSVC fails](https://godbolt.org/z/0qtFeF) -- notice calls to
`??0string@@QAE@$QAU0@@Z`, which is the move constructor of my local `string` class.

When I force the possible RVO case to run [by saying it is empty](https://godbolt.org/z/Mw16U1), you'll see that the compiler also fails to RVO optimize here; there is an `exit(-1)` inlined into the disassembly.

[Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/ApAG0H) manages to RVO the `return string();` but not NRVO the `return val;`.

By far the easiest fix is:

```
string DoIt(bool remove_all)
{
    if(g_report_generator.isEmpty())
        return string();

    return [&]{   
      string val = g_report_generator.GenerateReport();

      if(remove_all)
        g_report_generator.clear();

      return val;
    }();
}
```

which has double RVO, and a lambda that does simple NRVO.  Zero structural changes to your code, and functions which C++98 compilers can elide return values on (well, they don't support lambda, but you get the idea).

Comment: While `report` cannot be NRVO'd, the `std::string` return value constructed from it can be RVO'd directly into `val`. Although, since C++17, this it is no longer an optimisation, but rather required behaviour.

Comment: As far as I know, NRVO works only with id-expressions. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @eerorika Sorry, I read `return val` not `return report.c_str()` as not being NRVO'd.  My mistake.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the comprehensive explanation @Yakk-AdamNevraumont

Comment: So basically the "problem" is that I have 2 different return paths. What if I could somehow get rid of the if(remove_all) condition? If would return something like (g_report_generator.isEmpty() ? string() : g_report_generator.GenerateReport()), would RVO then be possible?

Comment: @conectionist Suggested practically elision-guaranteed solution added.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think (N)RVO is possible in either functions. `GenerateReport` has to construct a string from character array, there is nothing left for NRVO. `DoIt` returns two different values through it control path, which makes it impossible to perform NRVO as well.